# Dump video data from RAM DISK to the HARD DISK?

Tags: flash, ram, cache

This is the story:

Some online video streaming sites like **www.putlocker.com** won't allow **Adobe Flash Player** to cache the streaming videos on your **Hard Disk**, so the users can't watch them offline.
Instead they use **RAM Disk** to cache the streaming videos.

I was wondering, if there is a way to take off the data files I want, from the RAM and store them on my hard disk...
(May be by mounting the whole RAM as a filesystem or by a code)

I know there are video downloaders out there, but this question is for *educational purpose*, and may also apply to the other kind of data types rather than videos.

## Has anyone got a clue..?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [DDD](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/), a Front end of GDB, in which you can view and edit the contents of RAM. I'm not sure this is what you really need, but try check it out